# Django timestamp

Tags: python, django, file, time

Is there a way to use the Django timestamp without using a model? I want to write the timestamp to a file. The reason I want to use the Django one and not datetime or time from python is because I already set the Time Zone for it in settings so it would be more convenient if I could just use that.

Comment: what do you mean by `Django timestamp without using a model?`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur I was talking about models.DateTimeField() which gives a timestamp for models. I wanted something like that minus the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Also make sure that USE_TZ=True. This is automatically set to False. If this isn't set to True then timezone.now() will not be set to your timezone.

Comment: Perfect, I'll put this as the accepted answer since it's exactly what I was asking.

Comment: If you are still having trouble with this, try using timezone.localtime() instead of timezone.now()

Answer (score 3):

Django uses its module [`django.utils.timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/timezone/) to work with dates, times and perform convertions from/to locale or UTC datetimes. You can use functions from this module to do what you want.

In addition, you should [read the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) to understand how Django handle localized datetime.

Comment: Thanks for the link!!! I try to find documentation but it's hard sometimes when you're new to a framework and don't know how it's organized.